# Add a tag in angular ui seelct2 from controller after removing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

I want to add a tag again to angular ui select2 multiple selection after removing.

For eg. If I will remove one tag and call ajax whether user allowed to remove the tag and if not I want to add that tag. I am calling an ajax in $watch

```
<select ui-select2 data-placeholder="Pick Sports" multiple style="width: 100%;" name="sport_id" id="" ng-model="skillLevelForm.sport_id" required>

<option ng-repeat="sport in sports" value="{{sport.id}}">{{sport.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

js

```
$scope.$watch('skillLevelForm.sport_id', function(newV , oldV) {

       $scope.skillLevelForm.sport_id.push(oldV);            
});
```

Here oldV is an id that I am pushing back to ng-model      skillLevelForm.sport_id. that is can be seen in console log but tag is not added in ui. Plz help

Comment: are these `<option ng-repeat="sport in sports" value="{{sport.id}}">{{sport.name}}</option>` your tags? where is your code that removes a tag?

Comment: <option ng-repeat="sport in sports" value="{{sport.id}}">{{sport.name}}</option> is for the select2 dropdown and to cancel a tag there is no code simply click on cross button on tag to remove tag and I get event throught $watch

Comment: and you do something when you get notified, correct?

Comment: yeah i push in the array ng-model skillLevelForm.sport_id so that it become a tag in select2 but it does not reflect in dom